# Injected object in Application class is null

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have this module:

```
@Singleton
@Module(injects = { MyApplication.class }, library = true)
public class MyModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Configuration provideConfiguration() {
        Configuration config = Configuration.newInstance();

        return config;
    }
}
```

And I am injecting configuration inside my application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Inject
  Configuration config;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyModule());

    graph = ObjectGraph.create(list.toArray());

    graph.inject(this);
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that my Configuration is always null if I check it after `graph.inject(this);`. I was following this tutorial: http://antonioleiva.com/dagger-android-part-2/

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it a typo that your Configuration field is outside your class?

Comment: @AlexBaker, it's a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with this. I tried to reproduce the behaviour, but everything works as expected. The only thing I can think of, is that there might be something going on with the implementation of `Configuration` and its `.newInstance` static method. Make sure it's actually returning a non-null instance.